# What is the symbol for a Fan on a circuit? Is it just Motor?

Tags: dc-motor, schematics, fan

I've been looking around for the schematic symbol to use in a circuit drawing for a FAN. I'm not sure it exists. Do we use a Motor symbol when wanting to show a FAN? And just specify the motor ratings? IE 12V DC?

I've looked @ all the websites listed on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_symbols) as references for symbols and many Google searches.

After all, a FAN is just an electro-magnetic motor, isn't it? Does electronics specify at all between motors? (Not by 2 / 3 phase or various speed). But by different type?

I've also found symbols used in other engineering fields that specify a fan in their schematics. Can this be used?

So, essentially the question is, What symbol to use to specify a FAN in an electronic circuit?

Thanks all,

[image: Motor vs FAN symbol]

Comment: Top one is brushless, next one is brushed.

Comment: You may use a "motor" symbol to show its function, or you may simply use a "coil" symbol to show its electrical behaviour. In schematics, I usually use the latter.

Comment: Use the motor symbol and name is FAN1, FAN2 etc

Comment: Thank you all. Can someone please answer the question so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an electronic device schematic point of view, a fan simplifies thus:

Fan ==> Motor ==> Inductor coil(s)

Of course there are fans that do not use coils at all ([piezo fans](http://www.piezo.com/prodfan0nav.html), [coil-less motors](http://patent.ipexl.com/WO/WOZZSLASHZZ2008ZZSLASHZZ033093.html)), but let us set that aside for a moment.

At the lowest level of abstraction, thus, a purely electrical schematic symbol using one or more inductors **could suffice** to indicate a motor, such as these symbols for DC motors:

[image: DC motors]
([Source](http://emadrlc.blogspot.in/2013/05/standard-elementary-diagram-symbols_23.html))

Another [source](http://dmt195.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/bipolar-stepper-motor-control-with-picaxe-and-l293d-chips/) suggests the stepper motor symbols below:
[image: Stepper motors] ()

---

At a higher level of abstraction, the familiar symbol(s) with the letter "M" in a circular enclosure are commonplace, such as the brushless and brushed motor symbols illustrated in the question.

At a more pedantic level, some schematics use the M-circle symbol with a variety of enhancements to specify the various types of motors. [This page](http://gallery.proficad.com/symbols/electrical-installations/machines/motors/) provides an entire flood of symbols for specific motors.

[image: 3-phase series motor] [image: 3-phase unidirectional linear induction motor]

Note the use of both inductor and M-circle to address both electrical and functional symbolization in the 3-phase series motor above.

---

Even so, our symbols so far do not indicate the use of the motor for a fan. For fans specifically, there isn't any universally followed symbol AFAIK, but a few variants show up in [various](http://gallery.proficad.com/Symbols/others/miscellaneous/vehicles/) [documents](http://blogs.solidworks.com/teacher/2013/10/creating-symbols-in-solidworks-electrical-2d.html):

[image: Fan motor] (clearly, a fan!)

[image: Fan motor] (AC motor -> fan)

The "Other standards" fan symbols shown in the question are not so common in electronic design related schematics, they are used typically for process engineering and electrical wiring.

---

In summary, for lack of any universal standard, the symbol to be used is best determined by the purpose of the schematic: Is it important to account for inductive behavior, or to illustrate the type of motor, or at the most mundane and abstracted level, is it crucial to convey clearly that "*This motor here is a **fan***"?

Comment: This is spot on - it depends on the intended audience of the drawing, and what they need to know. For what it's worth, on electrical distribution single-line diagrams, motors are nearly always shown as just "M" and the function of the motor is added as an annotation, as in "No. 3 Ventilation Fan".

Comment: Great answer. That was good and I like the references. Thank you!